# How to get values from Extjs template

Tags: templates, extjs, textarea

I am using a Rowexpander inside a ExtjsGrid. RowExpander's template has text area which is used to get values from the user.

Below is my code.How can I read the value

```
var expander = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
        tpl : new Ext.Template(
    '<p><b></b><div class="abc"> <input type="textarea" id = "hans_" name ="hans_" value = "{comment}"</ div></p><p></p><p>{promptMsg}</p>'
                    ),
        listeners:
        {
            expand: function(ex, record, body, rowIndex){

            },
            collapse: function(ex, record, body, rowIndex){

      }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Solved ...It may help some other people

Answer (score 0):

Solved ...

Below is the solution

Give a dynamic names to textarea of template

```
'<p><b></b><div> <textarea rows="2" cols="100" id = "{qnNum}" name ="{qnNum}" >  {comment} </textarea><b></b></ div></p><p></p>'
```

Read the values

```
document.getElementById(record.data.qnNum);
```